# AddEventListener only works with the last picture

Tags: addeventlistener

I have one problem. addEventListener only works with the last element of the loop. I know what is the problem, but I can't figure it out. I get the JSON object from another function with the information. Later on the left side there should be clickable pictures. After clicking it I should get the same picture on the right side showed. Still it works only with the last one.

```
function myFunction(obj) {
    var listItems = document.getElementsByClassName("newimg");

    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        (function (i) {

        document.getElementById("imgSmall").innerHTML += `<br></br><img id="${i}"  class="newimg" src=${obj[i].download_url}  >`;


        let p = obj[i];
        listItems[i].addEventListener('click', function() { makeithappen(p);},true);


        }(i));

        //obj[i].width,obj[i].height,obj[i].author,obj[i].download_url>

    }
}

function makeithappen(k) {
    document.getElementById("imgLarge").innerHTML = `<br class="text"> AUTHOR: ${k.author}, WIDTH: ${k.width}, HEIGHT: ${k.height}</br><img class="img2" src=${k.download_url} >`;
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything immediately wrong with that, though you should really just use `let` instead of the silly IIFE version (since you're already using `let`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For quick fix.
Replace in your code

```
listItems[i].addEventListener('click', function() { makeithappen(p);},true);
```

with

```
listItems[i].onload = function() {
    listItems[i].addEventListener('click', function () { makeithappen(p); }, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So when you got your `listItems` you weren't finished with the creation of more images. So new image means new list.

```
for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {

    document.getElementById("imgSmall").innerHTML += `<br></br><img id="${i}"  class="newimg" src=${obj[i].download_url}>`;

    const listItems = document.getElementsByClassName("newimg");

    listItems[i].addEventListener('click', function () { makeithappen(p); }, true);
}

function makeithappen(k) {

    document.getElementById("imgLarge").innerHTML = `<br class="text"> AUTHOR: ${k.author}, WIDTH: ${k.width}, HEIGHT: ${k.height}</br><img class="img2" src=${k.download_url} >`;

}
```

Pleas do refactor `<br></br>` into something with css, margin or padding or whatever. This will then allow you to create the images with `let div = document.createElement('img')` and bind the event listener directly `div.addEventlistener(...)`